# InstrumentedHashset and overriding add & addAll

Tags: java, inheritance, collections

In Effective Java 2nd edition, Item 16, the author provides a scenario that illustrates "inheritence breaks encapsulation" where `InstrumentedHashSet` inherits from `HashSet` and overrides both methods `add()` and `addAll()`. My question is why the following alternative would not solve our problem for good? What sort of new problem(s) could occur :

```
public class InstrumentedHashSet<E> extends HashSet<E> {

    // The number of attempted element insertions
    private int addCount = 0;

    public InstrumentedHashSet() {
    }

    public InstrumentedHashSet(int initCap, float loadFactor) {
         super(initCap, loadFactor);
    }

    @Override public boolean add(E e) {
         addCount++;
         return super.add(e);
    }
    /* only the add method has been overrided
    @Override public boolean addAll(Collection<? extends E> c) {
         addCount += c.size();
         return super.addAll(c);
    }
    */

    public int getAddCount() {
         return addCount;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you remove an override for `addAll`, your `InstrumentedHashSet` would become vulnerable to changes in implementation of `addAll` in `HashSet<T>`.

Currently, [JDK implementation leaves the implementation up to its `AbstractCollection` base class](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/AbstractCollection.java#AbstractCollection.addAll%28java.util.Collection%29), which faithfully calls `add` for each item:

```
public boolean addAll(Collection<? extends E> c) {
    boolean modified = false;
    Iterator<? extends E> e = c.iterator();
    while (e.hasNext()) {
        if (add(e.next())) // <<== This will call your override
            modified = true;
    }
    return modified;
}
```

However, an alternative approach is possible: for example, `addAll` could try optimizing insertions by expanding hash bucket array at once inside `addAll` method, instead of calling `add` repeatedly. This would break the code, because `addCount` would no longer be properly maintained.

> [from the comment] What would incite the Java language designers in Oracle to change `HashSet<T>` implementation? Would not that break many java programs designed with the pre-knowledge that `addAll` calls add within its implementation?

That is precisely the point that Item 16 is trying to illustrate. Once others start inheriting from your class, you become "locked into" aspects of your implementation that are not explicitly stated in your program's code, such as one requiring `addAll` to call `add` on each item. In effect, inheriting broke encapsulation by "freezing" aspects of your code without your explicit acknowledgement.

Comment: I did not get how InstrumentedHashSet could become vulnerable to changes in  implementation of add in HashSet<T>. Could you please elaborate more on this providing more details.

Comment: @ecdhe I'm sorry, I meant to say to implementation of `addAll`. If they switch away from calling `add` on each item of `c`, your override would not be called, and `addCount` would be out of sync.

Comment: What would incite the Java language designers in Oracle to change HashSet<T> implementation? Would not that break many java programs designed with the pre-knowledge that addAll calls add within its implementation?

Comment: There are _lots_ of reasons to change internal implementation details.  HashSet has changed practically every release.  Depending on internal implementation details of HashSet, "designing with the pre-knowledge," is breaking encapsulation.  In general, your code should continue to work as long as all the _documented_ properties of an API remain true, even if the implementation details change.

Comment: Another risk is that a new method is *added* to the JDK API, as has occasionally happened. When this occurs, it's likely that its implementation will manipulate data structures directly instead of calling public methods like `add`. This has happened in the past, and it has broken code that subclassed a JDK class and that made unwarranted assumptions on the behavior of the superclass.